# cookies and session in login form

Tags: session, cookies

I need to create a login form with session and cookies . I tried a code in login as well as logout but the cookie is not working for me. I am a beginer kindly help and below is my code for login and log out. Thanx in advance
Login.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
$message="";
if(count($_POST)>0) {
$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','Spiegel@123','sachin') or 

die('Unable To connect');
$result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM login WHERE name='" .   
$_POST["name"] . "' and password = '". $_POST["password"]."'");
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
if(is_array($row)) {
$_SESSION["id"] = $row[id];
$_SESSION["name"] = $row[name];
} else {
$message = "Invalid Username or Password!";
}
}
if(isset($_SESSION["id"])) {

    setcookie("name", $_SESSION["name"], time()+60*60*24*100, "/");

header("Location:one.php");
}
?>
<html>
<head>
<title>User Login</title>
</head>
<body>
<form name="frmUser" id="frmUser" method="post" action="" align="center">
<div class="message"><?php if($message!="") { echo $message; } ?></div>
<h3 align="center">Enter Login Details</h3>
Username:<br>
<input type="text" name="name">
<br>
Password:<br>
<input type="password" name="password">
<br><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
<input type="reset">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Logout.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
if(session_destroy()) // Destroying All Sessions
{
    unset($_COOKIE['name']);
header("Location: login.php"); // Redirecting To Home Page
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to set cookie for time before now like below:

```
setcookie('name', null, -1, '/');
```